# Issue with UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm working with UITabBarController,

I select UITabBarController Tab its working fine (view controller and Tab image changed).

but when I try with code

```
AppDelegate.Tabctrl.selectedIndex = 2;
```

right view controller is selected but Tab image in 0th tab itself, I try with manual Image for TabBarController. Here is code.

```
-(void) LoadTabbarcontrol
{
    UIStoryboard *board  = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]; 

    AppDelegate.Tabctrl = [board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabbarCtrlId"];

    AppDelegate.Tabctrl.delegate = self;

    UIWindow *window = AppDelegate.window;
    [window addSubview:AppDelegate.Tabctrl.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    imgTab = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320.0,44.0)];
    imgTab.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tabbar_bg.png"];
    [AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar addSubview:imgTab];

    imgHome=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4.0,1.0,60.0,44.0)];
    imgHome.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home-Select.png"];
    [imgTab addSubview:imgHome];

    imgMyTc=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(67.0,1.0,60.0,44.0)];
    imgMyTc.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyTc.png"];
    [imgTab addSubview:imgMyTc];

    imgBrowse=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130.0,1.0,60.0,44.0)];
    imgBrowse.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Browse.png"];
    [imgTab addSubview:imgBrowse];

    imgInstore=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(193.0,1.0,60.0,44.0)];
    imgInstore.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Instore.png"];
    [imgTab addSubview:imgInstore];

    imgMore=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(256.0,1.0,60.0,44.0)];
    imgMore.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"More.png"];
    [imgTab addSubview:imgMore];

    AppDelegate.Tabctrl.view.hidden = NO;
    AppDelegate.Tabctrl.selectedIndex = 2;
}


    - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarControllers didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {
        if (tabBarControllers.selectedIndex == 0)
        {
            imgHome.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home-Select.png"];
            imgMyTc.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyTc.png"];
            imgBrowse.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Browse.png"];
            imgInstore.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Instore.png"];
            imgMore.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"More.png"];
        }
        else if (tabBarControllers.selectedIndex == 1)
        {
            imgHome.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"];
            imgMyTc.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyTc-Select.png"];
            imgBrowse.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Browse.png"];
            imgInstore.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Instore.png"];
            imgMore.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"More.png"];
        }
        else if (tabBarControllers.selectedIndex == 2)
        {
            imgHome.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"];
            imgMyTc.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyTc.png"];
            imgBrowse.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Browse-Select.png"];
            imgInstore.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Instore.png"];
            imgMore.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"More.png"];
        }
        else if (tabBarControllers.selectedIndex == 3)
        {
            imgHome.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"];
            imgMyTc.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyTc.png"];
            imgBrowse.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Browse.png"];
            imgInstore.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Instore-Select.png"];
            imgMore.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"More.png"];
        }
        else if (tabBarControllers.selectedIndex == 4)
        {
            imgHome.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"];
            imgMyTc.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyTc.png"];
            imgBrowse.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Browse.png"];
            imgInstore.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Instore.png"];
            imgMore.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"More-Select.png"];
        }
    }
```

can any one Help me for this?

Refer sample screen If I give

```
AppDelegate.Tabctrl.selectedIndex = 2;
```

Output like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code for change image of Tabbar controller:

```
 [[AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message12_64.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message_112_64.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add images by doing subview witch is not work because tabbar buttons are Button and they have image property too so add your icon image there, follow this small tutorial and read it before start so you will get understand

[UITabBarController Programmatically](http://www.xdracco.net/howto-implement-uinavigationcontroller-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically/)

for setting the tabbaritem image go with this

```
UITabBarItem *tabItem = [[[UITabBarItem tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:yourIndex];
[tabItem setTitle:@"theTitle"];
[tabItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
```